# SQL Select Statement -> query row with blocks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a normal select statement which is working :)
But I want that the query show in blocks an example:

**NOW**:

```
49810A58F778C8871AA01R
```

and I want this:

```
4981 0A58 F778 C887 1AA0 1R
```

The statement split the query in blocks. Is this possible with SQL?

Comment: Are all the field values the same length?

Comment: Hi, yes always the same lenght !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible method using `Stuff` function to manipulate the string

```
SELECT 
    -- Works only for length >= 21
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(
        '49810A58F778C8871AA01R'
    , 21, 0, ' '), 17, 0, ' '), 13, 0, ' '), 9, 0, ' '), 5, 0, ' ')
```

**Edit**

Add the `stuff` to `[IBAN]`

```
SELECT IBAN = STUFF((
    SELECT ';' + STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF([IBAN], 21, 0, ' '), 17, 0, ' '), 13, 0, ' '), 9, 0, ' '), 5, 0, ' ')
    FROM Bank   
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: look at the next post

Comment: @Artist_Styler_57 You should modify the question instead. Btw, see edit

Comment: okay thank you, should I ask a new question , or you can quickly respond to this :)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH